# Parametric Equations of an Ellipsoidal Helix

Tags: geometry

I am trying to construct the parametric equations of a general helix traced on the surface of an ellipsoid but I don't know how to put them on paper.

I know the parametric equations for an elliptical helix, but I don't know what should be done with them to make the helix trace the surface of an ellipsoid rather than a cylinder.

I suspected that I might find the answer in differential geometry textbooks, so I looked up some of them and found no useful information.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parametric equation of a circular helix are $$x=r\cos t\\y=r\sin t \\z=ct$$ To change to an elliptical helix, just put different radii for $x$ and $y$
$$x=A\cos t\\y=B\sin t \\z=Ct$$

For an ellipsoidal helix you need instead to modify $r$ such that $$\frac{r^2}{a^2}+\frac{z^2}{b^2}=1$$
$$r=a\sqrt{1-\frac{z^2}{b^2}}$$
So the answer is
$$x=a\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2t^2}{b^2}}\cos t\\y=a\sqrt{1-\frac{c^2t^2}{b^2}}\sin t\\z=ct$$
Note that $t\in\left[-\frac bc,\frac bc\right]$

Comment: I know that for "elliptical" helices, but what about "ellipsoidal" ones?

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question. I will modify the answer

Comment: Thanks so much!